# Quotes in the middle of the sentence

Tags: punctuation

Can I quote in the middle of the sentence or the whole sentence? Quote some words in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: Do you mean quoting something from somewhere else in the middle of your sentence or quoting the middle of someone else's sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is common to quote things in the middle of a sentence.

At times, one does so to highlight a term being defined/described, such as:

> 1) In my kitchen, there is a machine called a "food processor", which
>   chops up food into tiny pieces.
>
> 2) The "uvula" is that little organ that dangles in the back of your
>   throat.

At other times, quotes can be used in the middle of a sentence to imply that the writer doesn't agree with the use of the term, or thinks that it's misleading, inaccurate, etc. This is called "scare quotes". Some examples would be:

> 1) He just punched you in the face. Some "friend" he is.
>
> 2) They call themselves the Department of "Defense", but what they really
>   do is attack people in foreign countries.

Also, one can use quotes in the middle of a sentence when describing dialogue:

> 1) Alice said to her boss "Take this job and shove it!", and then
>   walked out with her head held high.
>
> 2) I said "Can I use your phone for a minute?", and he let me borrow his cell phone.